# How to install a Windows Service in Powershell when the commandline has quotes in it?

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have a service I need to install that has a commandline that looks something like this:

```
d:\My Service\service.exe /AsService /Config="d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config"
```

This is pretty much the worst-case scenario for a commandline. **The issue I have is with the double quotes in the args**.

This is what I've tried that is *close* but not quite:

```
$cmd = "create ""$ServiceName"" binPath= $FullServicePath start= $StartMethod"
Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c sc.exe $cmd" | Write-Host
```

Where `$FullServicePath` is:

```
d:\My Service\service.exe /AsService /Config="d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config"
```

Suggestions? I'm open to anything. WMI. Whatever.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're 100% sure that you need quotes, then you have to escape them with `\`:

```powershell
&'d:\My Service\service.exe' '/AsService' '/Config=\"d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config\"'
```

[Echoargs](https://chocolatey.org/packages/echoargs) output:

```powershell
Arg 0 is </AsService>
Arg 1 is </Config="d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config">
```

But probably this will work too and it's much easier:

```powershell
&'d:\My Service\service.exe' @('/AsService', '/Config=d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config\')
```

[Echoargs](https://chocolatey.org/packages/echoargs) output:

```powershell
Arg 0 is </AsService>
Arg 1 is </Config=d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `$FullServicePath` like this:

```
$FullServicePath = "d:\My Service\service.exe /AsService /Config=`"d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config`""
```

This uses the escape character  ` to tell it to process the quotes as text. (The escape character is the back tic next to the 1 key on most keyboards)

I believe you can also use this syntax:

```
$FullServicePath = $('d:\My Service\service.exe /AsService /Config="d:\Config Files\TheConfig.config"')
```

Both created the variable without a problem on my system.

When you call the `$FullServicePath` do it like this: `$($FullServicePath)`

Comment: I tried this, but I can't seem to pass it to sc.exe or installutil correctly. I've tried every which way, but it doesn't come out right.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you asked.  I added a different way to call the $FullServicePath.  Try this, see what happens.  I do this a lot when creating variables that are a combination of variables and calling variables with strange characters.

Answer (score -2):

This is a method i used .

[Installing a service in powershell](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2011/12/installing-windows-service-using.html)

Comment: Do you know whether or not the double quotes on the commandline would be supported? The article doesn't seem to indicate one way or the other.

Comment: I am not sure give it a try and if it does not work try some thing like this '"$ServiceName"' the ' should make powershell treat it as a string